# How to mark the corresponding time points when the switching function changes its value?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, labeling

`q[t]` is a switching function, and when

```
Mod [t, \ [Tau]=(2/3) \ [Tau]
```

`q[t]` changes from 1 to 0.

If I want to label the corresponding time point when the value of `q[t]` changes in the curve, what should I do?

This is my code：

```
tstart = 0;
tend = 0.06;
step = 0.00000005;
n = (tend - tstart)/step;
system = {vi q[t] == l iL'[t] + vC[t], 
   vC'[t] == iL[t]/c - vC[t]/(r c), vC[0] == 0, iL[0] == 0};
control = {q[0] == 1, 
   WhenEvent[Mod[t, \[Tau]] == (2/3) \[Tau], q[t] -> 0], 
   WhenEvent[Mod[t, \[Tau]] == 0, q[t] -> 1]};
pars = {vi -> 24, r -> 22, l -> 2 10^-2, 
   c -> 1 10^-4, \[Tau] -> 2.5 10^-5};
sol = NDSolve[{system, control} /. pars, {vC, iL, q}, {t, 0, .2}, 
   StartingStepSize -> step, 
   Method -> {"FixedStep", Method -> "LinearlyImplicitEuler"}, 
   DiscreteVariables -> q];
a = Evaluate[iL[t] /. sol];
b = Evaluate[vC[t] /. sol];
p1 = Plot[{a}, {t, 0, 0.08}, AxesLabel -> {"s", "il[t]/A"}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"LinearlyImplicitEuler"}, PlotStyle -> {Green}, 
  PlotRange -> All]
p2 = Plot[{b}, {t, 0, 0.08}, AxesLabel -> {"s", "vc[t]/A"}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"LinearlyImplicitEuler"}, PlotStyle -> {Yellow}, 
  PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "label the corresponding time point"? `PlotHighlighting -> Placed["Dropline", ...]`? Or `Callout`? Or something else?

Comment: I mean mark the points on the curve that corresponding to time t that satisfy the equation $Mod [t, \ [Tau]=(2/3) \ [Tau]]$

Comment: I mean, in what style? (Please check the document of `PlotHighlighting` and `Callout` to see if it's the style you want. If they're not, consider making a simple drawing illustrating what you want. ) And, are you sure you want to do this in the interval `{t, 0, 0.08}`? There're thousands of points satisfying the condition.

Comment: All methods that can display points are possible. Yes, I hope all the points that meet the requirements can be displayed in the graph. Before this, I tried using *Epilog*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be solved straightforwardly with `Sow`, `Reap` and `PlotHighlighting`. Though OP insist on visualizing on the whole `0<=t<=0.08` interval, I'll use `0.08/100` as the end time to show it doesn't make sense to draw so many points:

```
tstart = 0;
tend = 0.08;
system = {vi  q[t] == l  iL'[t] + vC[t], vC'[t] == iL[t]/c - vC[t]/(r  c), 
   vC[0] == 0, iL[0] == 0};
control = {q[0] == 1, 
   WhenEvent[Mod[t, τ] == (2/3)  τ, {Sow[t], q[t] -> 0}], 
   WhenEvent[Mod[t, τ] == 0, q[t] -> 1]};
pars = {vi -> 24, r -> 22, l -> 2  10^-2, c -> 1  10^-4, τ -> 2.5  10^-5};
{{vsol, isol, qsol}, {coord}} = 
  Reap@NDSolveValue[{system, control} /. pars, {vC, iL, q}, {t, 0, tend}, 
    DiscreteVariables -> q];

p1 = Plot[isol[t], {t, 0, tend/100}, AxesLabel -> {"s", "il(t)/A"}, 
  PlotStyle -> Green, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotHighlighting -> Placed["Dropline", coord]]
```

[image]

Comment: I used my Mathematica to run the code you shared, but the $PlotHighlighting$ and $Dropline$ displayed in red on my Mathematica and prompted the following error"*PlotHighlighting is not an option for plot*". Is it a problem with my mathematica version?

Comment: @chenchen, `PlotHighlighting` was introduced in version 13.3. I assume you are using an older version, right?

Comment: @Domen I think so, I am using version 13.2. I will try installing an updated version and running it again.